# Drupal 7: How to get this value with PHP

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-templates, drupal-entities

Please see the attached image below. I need to get the highlighted value via PHP and put it into one of my templates. I'm not exactly sure how this works, but this text is created as part of an [entityform](http://drupal.org/project/entityform) .

[image: Drupal Themer Info]

Comment: I've tried a few combinations like this which is how I'd grab a normal field value.. `$entity->field_title[$entity->language]['value'];` `$node->field_title[$node->language]['value'];`

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement [hook_form_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) in order to access a form element. Kindly read the documentation about how to use it.

Then, you can access the field like that:

```
$value = $form[YOUR_FIELD]['#items'][0]['value'];
```

Hope this works... Muhammad.